# Bootstrap: Grid structure, avoiding white space and moving columns around rows trouble

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Wondering if anyone can help, I'm building a Wordpress theme, but I think my specific issue is with Bootstrap so made sense to ask here! Theres a very easy way to do the below when handcoding, but to do with the way the Wordpress loop works I need to do it 'properly'.

I've got a page with images of people on it(approx 30 people)

[Example of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYyBk.png)

The objective is that when a user clicks on Person 1 a fact about Person 1 will appear from beneath them, when they click on Person 2, a fact about Person 2 will appear etc etc.

On desktop, I've got these split over 4 columns, on tablet 3 columns, and on mobile 2 columns. Everything works perfectly.  However, when I start to shrink the browser size down I get lots of white space. I know why this is, but I'm trying to find out the best way to tackle it. All the people are being pulled in with PHP in Wordpress so I need to build this a certain way.

This image should show what I'm after

[image: What I'd like and what I've got]

Whats the best way to go about this? Maybe nesting in Bootstrap?

Comment: This is tricky. You can add the facts to the person images as data attribute. onClick create the content below the appropriate image with some JS (insert after the last image that has y-pos the same as the clicked element). Have a listener to delete all inserted fact rows on resize.

Comment: I thought it may be, that definitely seems like a good option. I could also potentially have 3 different versions of the page (mobile/tablet/desktop) and serve a certain one depending on browser size, but this seems like a resource hog (esp on Wordpress). I'll look into your option and see where that gets me... Thanks

Comment: Other option is to have the fact box as position:fixed and sit over the top of everything, but thats visually different...

Comment: Duplicating html does not make the problem simpler. You still have to select te correct fact drawer and toggle it.